# If statement (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) trouble

Tags: php, select, if-statement

Running into trouble with the function below. Basically all my tables have a column in which 'discontinued' will either be '0' or '1'. I'm having trouble getting the if statement to work.

```
// Function that checks if items are already discontinued or not
function checkDiscontinued($dbh, $discontinued) {
try {
    foreach ($discontinued as $id) {
        //check to see if itemdiscontinued is 1 or 0
        $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT discontinued FROM `$id` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");

        if (!$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Action if true";
        }   else {
        echo "Action if false";
        }
    }
}
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble getting the if statement to work" -- What does that mean? How is `discontinued` stored? What's its type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch() method will always return true, no matter what your columns return as a result set (it should be common sense I guess).

What you need is to assign the value of the column to variable, and test the value.

```
const DISCONTINUED = 1;

function checkDiscontinued($dbh, $discontinued) {
try {
    foreach ($discontinued as $id) {
        $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT discontinued FROM `$id` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($row['discontinued'] == self::DISCONTINUED) { //if the column result == '1'
            echo "Action if true";
        }   else {
            echo "Action if false";
        }
    }
}
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```